# RegisterSingleton issue in Prism 7.2

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a class defined as follows (UPDATED):

```
    internal class SharedData : ISharedData
{

    public List<Gas> AllGases { get; set; }
    public List<Cylinder> AllCylinders { get; set; }
}
```

And the interface is defined as

```
    public interface ISharedData
{
    List<Gas> AllGases { get; set; }
    List<Cylinder> AllCylinders { get; set; }
}
```

and in the CylinderManagementModule.cs file, RegisterTypes function for the CylinderManagement project, I declare the singleton as:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISharedData,SharedData>();
```

My intension here is to share the SharedData items between multiple ViewModels and use ViewModel constructor injection to do it.  I added ISharedData in the ViewModel constructor parameter list, but when I run the application I get an error stating:

> Set property 'Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel' threw an InvalidRegistrationException (Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException').... and the InnerException states: No public constructor is available for type ISharedData

Can anyone advise me what the issue is here? Thanks!

UPDATE: After making the suggested changes with SharedData and ISharedData, I still get the same error.  The CylinderManagementModule.cs file RegisterTypes function now appears as:

```
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISharedData, SharedData>();
                       :
                       :
```

The CylinderManagementMainViewModel constructor appears as:

```
        public CylinderManagementMainViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager,
                                           IDialogService dialogService,
                                           ISharedData sharedData
                                          )
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        _sharedData = sharedData;
```

and the complete stack trace appears as:

> at Unity.UnityContainer.<>c.<.ctor>b__58_1(BuilderContext& context)
>      at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type, String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides)
>      at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(Object view, Action`2 setDataContextCallback)
>      at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>      at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)

UPDATE - I just determined that the CylinderManagementModule.cs RegisterTypes function is called AFTER the CylincerManagementMainViewModel constructor, in which case, the ISharedData in the CylincerManagementMainViewModel  constructor parameter list has not yet been added to the container. Again, my intent is to share the SharedData object between several ViewModels including the CylinderManagementMainViewModel shown above, so I'm assuming I'll have to do something different here.

Comment: I believe ```RegisterSingleton()``` is expecting to create a singleton instance lazily once any code attempts to resolve an instance of ```ISharedData``` from the container using a public, default constructor (e.g. ```new SharedData()```).  The default constructor is explicitly hidden because it's scoped with ```private```.  Instead I think you instead want to use ```containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ISharedData>(SharedData.Instance);```... may need to pass in an instance of ```IContainerControlledLifetimeManager``` as well but I believe that is the default lifetime manager.

Comment: Do register instance

Comment: I just determined that the ModuleX RegisterTypes function is called AFTER the ModuleX ViewModel constructor, in which case, the ISharedData in the ModuleX ViewModel constructor parameter list has not yet been added to the container.  Again, my intent is to share the SharedData object between several ViewModels, so I'm assuming I'll have to do something different.

Comment: See my edited answer - the shell's indeed created before module initialization, so you can register `ISharedData` from the main app for it to be available to the shell's view model (in addition to all view models defined in modules, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, what I was trying to do here was create a SharedData object that could be accessed in multiple ViewModels **within the same project**.  I declared the SharedData in the Module file, RegisterTypes function for the project, and tried to reference the ISharedData object in the primary ViewModel constructor parameter list.

What I determined, though, was the the RegisterTypes function was NOT executed BEFORE the ViewModel constructor was called, and therefore, the ISharedData parameter had not yet been registered with the container, and resulted in the error documented above.  That the module RegisterTypes function was not executed before the ViewModel constructor was executed was a bit of a surprise to me, but I guess you learn something new everyday.

Comment: It's a surprise to me, too. Do you load the module on demand?

Comment: The module is added to the module catalog in the ConfigureModuleCatalog function in the App.xaml.cs file.  Other than that, I do no other module manipulation.

Comment: And you create the main window view model through the viewmodellocator, too?

Comment: Yes, the main window view model is created via the viewmodellocator.  The module that I am referring to above is navigated to from the main window.  For now, I have moved the RegisterSingleton ISharedData to the App.xaml.cs file so that I can move forward with development. I do NOT plan to keep it there and would preferably like it in the module above where it will be used, once I figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Just a clarification ... The apps MAIN window contains tabs that allow the user to navigate to different functional parts (modules) within the app.  The primary VIEW of the ModuleX project referred to above, is navigated to by selecting a tab on the MAIN window.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all this

```
private static readonly SharedData instance = new SharedData();

// Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
// not to mark type as beforefieldinit
static SharedData() { }

private SharedData() { }

public static SharedData Instance
{
    get { return instance; }
}
```

and use `RegisterSingleton` and you're fine. And the code is simpler.

But you want to make `SharedData` internal and only `ISharedData` public.

Edit:

If you try to register `ISharedData` in a module and consume it in the shell's view model, you're indeed out of luck.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/f76990baff9b868ce0f5ab8bdcab481e4b4e6012/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs#L64), the shell is created before module initialization. So one has to move code that has dependencies filled by modules from the shell itself into a view that's navigated to in `PrismApplicationBase.OnInitialized`. Or, alternatively, move the code that fills the dependency into the main application.

Comment: After making the suggested changes, I still get the same error .... documentation above has been updated

Comment: I just determined that the ModuleX RegisterTypes function is called AFTER the ModuleX ViewModel constructor, in which case, the ISharedData in the ModuleX ViewModel constructor parameter list has not yet been added to the container. Again, my intent is to share the SharedData object between several ViewModels, so I'm assuming I'll have to do something different

Comment: How do you create the ModuleX ViewModel? I suppose it should not be created before the registration is done unless you create it manually. Registering as singleton is definitively the way to go, that way _the container _ will create the shared instance when required.

Comment: Using Prism 7.2 .... I just have the prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" entry in the View .... so whenever that results in the ViewModel constructor being called.

Comment: I may have introduced a bit of confusion here .... I tried to register the ISharedData in a module and consume it in the SAME MODULE, passing the ISharedData to different ViewModels, via constructor injection, within the SAME MODULE.  There are multiple Views/ViewModels defined in this SAME MODULE, but there is one primary View/ViewModel in this Module, and that's where I originally tried to inject ISharedData via the ViewModel constructor.

Comment: Then how can the view model contained in the module be created before registration in the module is done if you don't do it yourself? It would really help if you could show us some actual code, like the complete module definition. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: What I would like is for the RegisterTypes function for the module to be executed BEFORE the primary ViewModel constructor is executed.  That is ultimately what caused me to write up this issue to begin with.  At this time, the primary ViewModel constructor is executed BEFORE the RegisterTypes function executes.

Comment: Please show the module initialization code. Whatever the primary view model is, you must somehow create it yourself prematurely, because the framework won't do that on its own.